# Can Fabric know to expect a host to disconnect?

Tags: python, networking, automation, fabric, openwrt

I'm writing a Fabric script to provision some OpenWRT access points. Part of my script involves assigning a new static IP to the APs, which requires restarting the network interface.

My problem is that when I do this, Fabric hangs because the connection to the host disappears.

Is there a way to tell Fabric to either:

1. Expect this command to fail to return
2. Connect to the new host IP automatically

For reference, this is the output from the task:

```
[root@192.168.1.1:22] run: uci set network.lan.proto=static
[root@192.168.1.1:22] run: uci set network.lan.ipaddr=<my IP here>
[root@192.168.1.1:22] run: uci commit network
[root@192.168.1.1:22] run: /etc/init.d/network reload

<Fabric hangs indefinitely>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting [`env.command_timeout`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/env.html#command-timeout) and then calling the function that sets static IPs with [`execute`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute).

> **`command_timeout`**
>
> **Default**: `None`
>
> Remote command timeout, in seconds.